# adding js files to .net with Bundling and Minification

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, minify

I normally have something like this in the `<head>` of my aspx page

```
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery-ui-1.8.24.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.floatingFixed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery/waypoints.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

after watching [This Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pIv6yR9Q1IA) Scott Guthrie says that this is no longer needed , that you can add all .js files from a file in one `<script>` tag and .Net will automatically minify and bundil it for you.  Like so

```
 <script src="jquery/js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
```

EDIT:  I know that this can be done with numerous third party tools , but he does it in the video with .Net - and explains how the .Net minification compares to third party minification (meaning he is not using a third party tool)

Now.. I understand this is a video on MVC 4, but he says that this is also available in WebForms .  I am using VS 2010 sp1 (.Net 4.0) with MVC 4 installed and it is not working, is there some tool that I am missing that I need to add?  or is this only for VS 2011 and VS 2012?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bundling is handled by `Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization` which can be found in NuGet and used within your templates to output the bundled script / styles.